# How update related data in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two table with many to many relationship in ASP.NET MVC like this:

```
public class Course
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Capacity { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<DayTime> DayTimes{ set; get; }
}

public class DayTime
{
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public WeekDaysEn Day { get; set; }
       public string StartTime { get; set; }
       public string EndTime { get; set; }
       public virtual ICollection<Course> Course{ get; set; }
}
```

and when the record in `Course` is like:

```
{
    id = 1,
    title = 'test',
    capacity = 20, 
    { 
        DayTimes = { id = 2, Day = 0, StartTime = '10:00', endTime = '12:00' }
    }
}
```

When I try to update this and define data like:

```
{id=1,title='test',capacity=20, 
                  {DayTimes={id=2,Day=0,StartTime='10:00',endTime='12:00'},
                            {id=2,Day=0,StartTime='12:00',endTime='14:00'}
}
```

The new `DayTime` record is not updated in the `CourseDayTime` table

Comment: how you are updating those data ? with entity files please provide source code for the same so it would be easy to find out issue

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework to update your database with the above data?